# PHP variable returns a null value

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, textbox

I've created a textbox so when the admin types a name and clicks submit, it will shows a list of retrieved data from the database.

```
    <form method="post" action="">
        <?php 
        $teacherName = $_POST['teacherName'];
        if ($_POST['submitted'] == 1) {
            if($teacherName != ""){
                $getName = mysql_query("SELECT name, user_id FROM members WHERE name = '$teacherName'");
                $teacherdetails = mysql_fetch_array($getName);
                $teachername = $teacherdetails['name'];
                $teacher_id = $teacherdetails['user_id'];

                if($teachername != ""){
                    print $teachername . "<br/>";
                } else {
                    print "Give a valid name <br/>";
                }     
            }
        }

        if ($teachername == ""){ ?>
        Teacher name:<input type="text" size="20" name="teacherName"><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1"><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 


<?php $getModule = mysql_query("......"); 
          while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($getModule)) { ?>   
          <input type="checkbox" name="modules[]" value="<?php print $row2["module_id"]?>"/> <?php print $row2["module_name"] . '<br/>'; } ?>
          </div><br/> <?php } ?>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Below I wrote this code (in the same script):

```
<?php

$modules = $_POST['modules'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($modules); $i++){
    $module=mysql_query("INSERT INTO module (module_id,user_id) VALUES ('$modules[$i]','$teacher_id')"); 
}
?>
```

but for some reason when I call the variable "$teacher_id" (which is the value I retrieved before from the database. It works fine in the form) it returns nothing. It's null but I can't understand why.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you please post a dump of $teacherdetails? Thanks.

Comment: You're using a deprecated library with sql injection vulnerable code

Comment: Are both calls definitely in the same scope?

Comment: im really sorry guys but can u explain it in more details please? I don't really understand what u mean. :(

Comment: Both are in the same script, one in the form and the second one in php below the html form.

Comment: @savvas999 But are ether inside a function?

Comment: hm no they are not. Do I need a function to pass variable values though? Cause i've done that so many times and it worked fine.

Comment: @savvas999 Nope, I was making sure they where in same scope. What is output of `var_dump($teacherdetails)` ?

Comment: (savvas999 is the name i typed in the textbox)

array
  0 => string 'savvas999' (length=9)
  'name' => string 'savvas999' (length=9)
  1 => string '10' (length=2)
  'user_id' => string '10' (length=2)

Comment: btw I'm using two submit buttons, one to get the name, and one to get the modules values. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

First off, put the PHP outside the form tags, at the top.

Secondly, the data you are receiving could be an array; with more than one result set;

do this just incase it it returned as that;

```
 foreach($teacherdetails AS $teacher) {
//also set the values of the variables here
echo $teacher['name'];
echo $teacher['user_id'];

}
```

Regarding the last bit, is the $teacher_id successfully printing a result?

Also, where is the modules being input and posted from?

Comment: it's always ONLY one name. and it works fine in the form. If I try to print $teacher['name']; and $teacher['user_id']; it will work fine. The problem is when I call the $teacher_id in PHP.

Comment: Echo both the name and id at the bottom of the page and see if it gives a result.

Comment: I have a query inside the form if im not wrong. I didn't add it because it's huge. I can do it now if u want

Comment: Yes please it would be helpful

Comment: it gives a result if the variables are outside the for loop. So i think the problem is the for loop... for($i = 0; $i < count($modules); $i++){ ... }

Comment: i've just added the getModule query. Hm i'm using two submit values, one to get the name, and one to get the modules values. Is that ok?

Comment: Okay, not echo out the $modules in the last bit, to check they are set.

Comment: yep the modules in the last bit are working fine. It prints multiple values, i try with one, two and three checkboxes selected and it's fine. So I get the module values but not the teacher id. If I put a print statement OUTSIDE the for loop then it prints the teacher_id as well.

Comment: yeah, that's the problem. If I print teacher ID inside the for loop it returns a null value. If I print it outside then it prints the value as expected

Comment: Where abouts in the for statement did you print, before the query or after?

Comment: I'm talking about this ''for($i = 0; $i < count($modules); $i++){ $module=mysql_query("INSERT INTO module (module_id,user_id) VALUES ('$modules[$i]','$teacher_id')"); }''

Comment: It's after the modules query.

Comment: im getting the same result. Modules values are fine, teacher id is null.